picframe Install on Raspberry Pi 3B, Bullseye OS, pi-heif wheel fails to build
Novice Raspberry Pi user here trying to build a digital picture frame. The problem I'm running into is the pi-heif wheel won't successfully build.
I'm using Python3.11.2, the latest libheif library is installed, and I've run all the precursory installs necessary (sudo apt-get update, python3 -m pip install -U pip, etc).
Looking through pi-heif or pillow-heif documentation doesn't provide any alternative install options or troubleshooting help.
When trying to run python3 -m pip install pi-heif or any variation of it, I'm given the error codes :
error: command '/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit code 1
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pi-heif

I'm wondering if anyone has run into a similar problem or successfully installed pi-heif on their raspberry pi? It seems to fail building on the Bookworm OS but there are a number of accounts I can find of people using picframe on their raspberries. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!
Full error message:
bash ~ $python3 -m pip install pi-heif
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting pi-heif
  Using cached pi_heif-0.20.0.tar.gz (16.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=10.1.0 in ./vene/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pi-heif) (11.0.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: pi-heif
  Building wheel for pi-heif (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pi-heif (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [46 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-311/pi_heif
      copying pi_heif/constants.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-311/pi_heif
      copying pi_heif/heif.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-311/pi_heif
      copying pi_heif/_deffered_error.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-311/pi_heif
      copying pi_heif/misc.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-311/pi_heif
      copying pi_heif/AvifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-311/pi_heif
      copying pi_heif/options.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-311/pi_heif
      copying pi_heif/HeifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-311/pi_heif
      copying pi_heif/as_plugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-311/pi_heif
      copying pi_heif/_lib_info.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-311/pi_heif
      copying pi_heif/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-311/pi_heif
      copying pi_heif/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-311/pi_heif
      running build_ext
      Looking for `libheif` using pkg-config.
      Checking for include file 'heif.h' in '/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf'
      Checking for include file 'heif.h' in '/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libheif'
      Found 'heif.h' in '/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libheif'
      building '_pi_heif' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-311/pi_heif
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/include -I/home/serbu/vene/include -I/usr/local/include -I/home/serbu/vene/include -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c pi_heif/_pi_heif.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-311/pi_heif/_pi_heif.o -Ofast -Werror
      pi_heif/_pi_heif.c: In function ‘_CtxAuxImage’:
      pi_heif/_pi_heif.c:760:21: error: implicit declaration of function ‘heif_image_handle_get_preferred_decoding_colorspace’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
        760 |     if (check_error(heif_image_handle_get_preferred_decoding_colorspace(aux_handle, &colorspace, &chroma))) {
            |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      pi_heif/_pi_heif.c:760:21: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘check_error’
        760 |     if (check_error(heif_image_handle_get_preferred_decoding_colorspace(aux_handle, &colorspace, &chroma))) {
            |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            |                     |
            |                     int
      pi_heif/_pi_heif.c:14:35: note: expected ‘struct heif_error’ but argument is of type ‘int’
         14 | int check_error(struct heif_error error) {
            |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
      pi_heif/_pi_heif.c: In function ‘_get_aux_type’:
      pi_heif/_pi_heif.c:1310:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘heif_image_handle_release_auxiliary_type’; did you mean ‘heif_image_handle_free_auxiliary_types’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
       1310 |     heif_image_handle_release_auxiliary_type(aux_handle, &aux_type_c);
            |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            |     heif_image_handle_free_auxiliary_types
      pi_heif/_pi_heif.c: In function ‘_load_file’:
      pi_heif/_pi_heif.c:1510:21: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct heif_error’ from type ‘int’
       1510 |             error = heif_image_handle_get_preferred_decoding_colorspace(handle, &colorspace, &chroma);
            |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
      error: command '/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pi-heif
Failed to build pi-heif
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml b
```ased projects (pi-heif)


python3 -m pip install wheel

pip3 install wheel


Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=10.1.0 in
./vene/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pi-heif) (11.0.0)

You need to install latest PILLOW version 11.0.0.
Mine is older version 9.5.0.
On your side, you need to install python3 -m pip install wheel before install pi-heif.
Today, I tried your command python3 -m pip install pi-heif
Here you can see my output using Bullseye Pi 3B:
supra@pi:~ $ python3 -m pip install pi-heif
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting pi-heif
  Downloading pi_heif-0.20.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (936 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 936 kB 4.2 MB/s 
Collecting pillow>=10.1.0
  Downloading pillow-11.0.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_28_aarch64.whl (4.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 4.2 MB 6.3 MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pillow, pi-heif
  Attempting uninstall: pillow
    Found existing installation: Pillow 9.5.0
    Uninstalling Pillow-9.5.0:
      Successfully uninstalled Pillow-9.5.0
Successfully installed pi-heif-0.20.0 pillow-11.0.0

